# How to change Skype language on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, internationalization, skype

I have an iPad with Settings->General->International->Language set to Hungarian. Still, my Skype is in Chinese and I have no idea how to change that.

I tried to change the iPad's language, to change the language in my Skype profile, to reinstall Skype, to delete Skype's backup in iCloud than to reinstall, but no use.

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you change the iPad user interface language to? Skype like most other apps should adjust to that, as long as it is one of the languages it comes with.

Comment: I changed to English, than back to Hungarian. Indeed, Chinese was the second after Hungarian, that's why Skype used Chinese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype doesn't come in Hungarian (see the info published on the app store page for it). So it probably takes the next priority on your OS.  Is Chinese second on your Language list? If so, move English to the top temporarily so that it becomes the default after Hungarian.